# Redux Form: Accessing FieldArray fields prop from outside wrapped component

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a form that consists of several classical fields and two FieldArray's. These FieldArrays are in separate sections but are interrelated. When I add an item to FieldArray A, (a row of different kinds of fields), another row for the FieldArray B should be built. FieldArray A and B are different in the sense that they represent a different collection and structure of fields, however, when a row is added into A, a row must be added into B.

In order to add a row to FieldArray A, I follow the documented method of using the *push* method into the prop fields, inside the wrapped component of FieldArray A. However I have no access to the prop fields of FieldArray B. That prop is only accessible from within the wrapped component inside FieldArray B.

Is there another way or a method to get access to the prop fields of FieldArray B from outside of it? formValues() or formValuesSelector() are not useful.

Comment: Could you include your code? I would imagine you would need to wrap both A and B in a HOC and bind the handlers for A and B to the HOC, therefore allowing the HOC to control the state of both. But seeing the actual structure of your form would help in understanding the issue better

Comment: @AdamJohnston Never mind after digging and digging for non-documented methods of redux-form i found the action creator `arrayPush` of the library that when you pass the arguments formId, field and value ... it pushes a new value programatically into the field array. I will publish a self-answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so after digging the documentation of redux-form for hidden features... i found out that you can import from redux-form its action creators, particularly `arrayPush` which lets you *push* a new "row" of fields by specifying the formid, fieldarray name and value like this:

Given a redux-form with id: 'myForm', a `FieldArray` with name 'nested_model_attributes' and a `value = [subfield1: 'A', subfield2: 2, ... ]`

you can dispatch the following:

`arrayPush('myForm', 'nested_model_attributes', value)`

And voila... the FieldArray adds a new row of fields :). In this case, this is the FieldArray B i was referring to in the original question. All i need to do is dispatch this method from where i pushed a new row of fields to FieldArray A.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to a solution to this @tommyalvarez!  I had a few problems with accessing the `arrayPush` action creator directly.  I blogged about it here: https://calendee.com/2018/09/22/adding-to-redux-form-fieldarray/

Comment: Did't worked properly with my RF version so I ended up like so since action creators are plain objects: ```const arrayPush = () => ({
  type: '@@redux-form/ARRAY_PUSH',
  meta: {
    form: 'wpTypes',
    field: 'types'
  },
  payload: {}
});```